# Installing Gazebo package in simulator_gazebo ROS stack on OSX Lion

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am having a hard time getting the gazebo package in the simulator_gazebo stack to compile on Lion.

I can get all the ROS package dependencies installed, but when compiling Gazebo itself, I get a compilation error that looks like this:

---

-- BUILD WARNINGS
--    CEGUI not found, opengl GUI will be disabled.
--    Player not found, gazebo plugin for player will not be built.
-- END BUILD WARNINGS

-- BUILD ERRORS: These must be resolved before compiling.
--    Missing: tinyxml
--    Missing: TBB - Threading Building Blocks
-- END BUILD ERRORS

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:193 (message):
Errors encountered in build.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make[1]: *** [installed] Error 1
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:29 (message):
Build of Gazebo failed

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

---

I have installed both of the packages tinyxml and tbb from Homebrew, but the install script seems to be unable to find them.

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/50/installing-gazebo-package-in-simulator_gazebo-ros-stack-on-osx-lion/) by [zlittlefield](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42/zlittlefield/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zlittlefield](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42/zlittlefield/) on 2012-10-18**:
While waiting for the question to be posted, I figured out the answer to this question.  pkg-config couldn't find the library files because there were no .pc files created to find these libraries. Manually creating them solved this issue.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2012-10-18**:
So you got gazebo installed?

**Comment by [zlittlefield](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42/zlittlefield/) on 2012-10-21**:
No, other problems have arisen since then. I haven't had a chance to continue trying to install it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Quoting zlittelfield's comment as an answer:

While waiting for the question to be posted, I figured out the answer to this question. pkg-config couldn't find the library files because there were no .pc files created to find these libraries. Manually creating them solved this issue.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/242/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-03-10**:
how create manually?

**Comment by [Andrew Hundt](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/685/andrew-hundt/) on 2014-03-24**:
I second the question.